# Дана строка. Выведите в консоль длину этой строки

Tags: java, строки, scanner

Почему он считает тип `int` за строку?

```
package org.example;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Введите строку: ");
        String str = input.nextLine();

        int length = str.length();

        System.out.println("Длина строки:" + length);

        if (!input.hasNext())
            System.out.println("Введите только текст!");
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно исправить ошибку, желательно не используя какие-то новые методы, функции и т.д.?

Comment: покажите на примере, что именно вас не устраивает

Comment: Введите строку: 345345
Длина строки:6

Comment: А мне нужно чтобы выводил что это числа, а не строки, также можно и с символами сделать, (кроме букв алфавита)

Comment: Ну так вы получаете длинну строки, если вам нужно получить само число (int), нужно конвертировать строку в int.

Comment: Мне нужно проверять длину строки, но если пользователь видеть числа как строку то выдать ошибку. Можно вводить только буквы из алфавита то есть тип String

Comment: Тип String может содержать любые символы - и буквы, и цифры, и знаки препинания, и вообще смайлики всякие. Так что вводите строку, и проверяете её, например, с помощью **регулярных выражений**. Можно и посимвольно проверять - с помощью сравнений с "A/Z" или вхождением во множество нужных символов. Или воспользоваться функцией `isAlphabetic() `

Answer (score 2):

Предположение, что тип `String` содержит *"только буквы из алфавита"* изначально неверно, так как строки содержат любые символы (а не только буквы из *разных* алфавитов), включая цифры, знаки пунктуации, пробельные символы, специальные символы.

Если для ввода данных используется метод `Scanner::nextLine`, то будет возвращаться строка с *любыми* символами, *кроме символа перевода строки*, то есть такая строка вполне может содержать несколько *слов*, разделённых пробельными символами.

Метод [`Scanner::next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) также используется для ввода *строк (токенов)*, разделённых (по умолчанию) любыми *пробельными символами*.

Однако судя по неявно описанному условию задачи, в ней необходимо ограничить диапазон вводимых символов (в данном случае "буквами из алфавита"), то для ввода данных нужно использовать перегруженный вариант данного метода [`Scanner::next(String pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next-java.lang.String-), принимающий на вход *шаблон*, описывающий допустимый формат строки.
Примеры шаблонов:

- Только буквы из *разных алфавитов*: `scanner.next("\\p{L}+")`
- Только прописные(большие) буквы из *разных алфавитов*: `scanner.next("\\p{Lu}+")`
- Буквы только из *английского алфавита*: `scanner.next("[A-Za-z]+")`
- Буквы только из *русского алфавита*: `scanner.next("[А-Яа-яЁё]+")`
- Буквы из *русского и английского алфавитов*: `scanner.next("[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+")`
- Любые непробельные нецифровые символы: `scanner.next("\\D+")`

Следует учесть, что признаком окончания ввода будет ввод пробельного символа.
При обнаружении в токене любого символа, не удовлетворяющего указанному шаблону, будет выброшено исключение `InputMismatchException`.

Пример:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("введите строку: ");

String str = sc.next("\\p{L}+");

System.out.println("длина строки: " + str.length());
```

Результаты:

```
введите строку: 
абв12 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:947)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1533)
```

```
введите строку: 
hello
длина строки: 5
```